# How to generate a integrity hash for link elements

Tags: html

Bootstrap CDN is using the subresource integrity, i'm looking for how to generate this hash.

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
      rel="stylesheet" 
      integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" 
      crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://www.srihash.org/ should do the trick; it will generate a hash given whatever URL you want to use.